Determine the likelihood given random sampling that your samples are actually coming from two distinct sets
In most experiments, you have a control and experimental group. At the end of the study, you run a t-test or similar to determine if the two populations are significantly different from one another. This is the basis of most research.
In a situation where you are blinded, is there a way you can bootstrap by randomly sampling without knowing which group the sample comes from to answer the following question:
Once unblinded, if there were a true difference, would it be detectable? As in, was variation tight enough that once unblinded, you could even make the determination?

Are you familiar with permutation tests? It sounds like you're describing something like this.

Looks promising. I'll read into it more. Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
